# Objective C Class may not respond to methord

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C and I was trying to create a sample program on my own. When I compiled the code in my Linux machine I was getting enough warnings and it was compiled. But surprisingly I got no output instead I got many messages. The code description was given below

> Method Declaration

```
    @interface AsciitoBinaryClass:NSObject
    /* method declaration */
    - (int)AsciitoBinary: (char)d Num1:(int*)bin ;
   @end
```

> Method

```
@implementation AsciitoBinaryClass
    /* method Convert Ascii to Binary */
    - (int)AsciitoBinary: (char)d Num1:(int*)bin{
        int len=0;
        int a=d;
        while(a>0)
        {
            bin[len]=a%2;
            a/=2;
            len++;
        }
        return len;
    }
@end
```

> Method call from Main

```
AsciitoBinaryClass *asciitobinaryClass = [[AsciitoBinaryClass alloc]init];
    len = [asciitobinaryClass AsciitoBinary:a Num2:bin];
```

The compilation warnings are given below

```
shameerariff@shameerariff-Lenovo-G460:~/study/c/crypt/objc$ gcc test.m -o test  `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `gnustep-config --base-libs`
test.m: In function ‘main’:
test.m:35:2: warning: ‘AsciitoBinaryClass’ may not respond to ‘-AsciitoBinary:Num2:’
  len = [asciitobinaryClass AsciitoBinary:a Num2:bin];
  ^
test.m:35:2: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
test.m:35:2: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept
test.m:35:2: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.)
test.m:35:6: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  len = [asciitobinaryClass AsciitoBinary:a Num2:bin];
      ^
test.m:32:13: warning: variable ‘len’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int bin[8],len=0;
```

The messages during runtime

```
shameerariff@shameerariff-Lenovo-G460:~/study/c/crypt/objc$ ./test 
2016-05-03 15:25:02.600 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x2607270) of class GSCInlineString in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.616 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x2745330) of class NSException in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.616 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x2744530) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.616 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x2735790) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.617 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x2732dc0) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.617 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x2734260) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.617 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x26ae280) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.617 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x264c610) of class NSIntNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.617 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x2653490) of class NSLongLongNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
2016-05-03 15:25:02.617 test[22624] autorelease called without pool for object (0x264af40) of class NSIntNumber in thread <NSThread: 0x2593270>
./test: Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[AsciitoBinaryClass AsciitoBinary:Num2:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2598520
shameerariff@shameerariff-Lenovo-G460:~/study/c/crypt/objc$
```

Comment: I already tested this program which I written in C and It was doing good with out any issues...

Comment: Don't spam tags! C, C++ and ObjC are all different languages (with one exception, which is irrelevant here).

Comment: Since Obj C is derived from C and C++ I added C and C++ in the Tag.

Comment: ObjC is **not** derived from C++. Both are developed from C. But your code is not C and the warnings are clearly about ObjC features, thus the C tag is wrong, too. But for all these languages: Pay heed to warnings!

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your advice, since I am newly started I was in the different impression, After seeing your post I verified, You are almost correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your method as:

```
- (int)AsciitoBinary: (char)d Num1:(int*)bin;
```

And you are calling it as:

```
- (int)AsciitoBinary: (char)d Num2:(int*)bin ;
```

`AsciitoBinary:Num1:` and `AsciitoBinary:Num2:` does not have the same erasure.

In your main function replace:

```
AsciitoBinaryClass *asciitobinaryClass = [[AsciitoBinaryClass alloc]init];
len = [asciitobinaryClass AsciitoBinary:a Num2:bin];
```

by

```
AsciitoBinaryClass *asciitobinaryClass = [[AsciitoBinaryClass alloc]init];
len = [asciitobinaryClass AsciitoBinary:a Num1:bin];
```

Comment: Thank you  Xvolks since I am new to this format I committed this mistake.

Comment: @Shameerariff If you want to follow ObjC naming conventions, the method should be `-(int)asciiToBinary:... num1:...;`

Comment: @bbum Thank you from now on I will follow this. I am just started with Obj C, I am not so familiar with everything. I am practicing Obj C on converting my existed C projects to Obj C.